# A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

Good afternoon, totally stumped on this one. everything was going fine until I added more records into my database.

On pressing edit I get this error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

My code is as follows:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Time time = db.Times.Single(t => t.index == id);
        return View(time);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Default1/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Time time)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HERE");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Times.Attach(time);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(time, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(time);
    }
```

I havent been programming MVC for that long, so laymans terms would be welcome!

thanks

Comment: Make sure that .Single(t => t.index ==id) is returning one record. Single returns a single item and throw an exception if there is either none or more than one item.

Comment: Hi, there is only one records in the db at the moment. Im yet to populated it with masses of data.

Comment: What does it mean "everything was going fine until I added more records into my database"

Comment: i started with one row, then added more, all the time refreshing the model, but went back to one due to the concurrency issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have started a new project and copied over the entire code from the controllers, etc, it seems to have worked.

I think the main issue I had was to make too many changes to the model with the primary key etc and basically was my bad.

Better database architecting needed!!!!